ng build cause warnings with pseudo-selectors
I am getting errors during ng build
[WARNING] 6 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .amplify-accordion__item:where() -> Empty sub-selector
  .amplify-accordion__item:where() -> Empty sub-selector
  0% -> Unmatched selector: %
  50% -> Unmatched selector: %
  0% -> Unmatched selector: %
  50% -> Unmatched selector: %

I have upgraded my app from Angular v16 to Angular v17 and updated aws packages with the current latest versions given below.
"dependencies": {
  // skipped rest of the packages
  "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^5.0.14",
  "@aws-sdk/client-quicksight": "^3.574.0",
  "amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk": "^2.7.0",
  "aws-amplify": "^6.3.0",
}


Resolved this issue by adding the following configs to production in angular.json file.
"configurations": {
  // skipped rest of the code for clarity
  "production": {
    "optimization": {
      "scripts": true,
      "styles": {
        "minify": true,
        "inlineCritical": false
      },
      "fonts": true
    }
  }
  // skipped rest of the code for clarity
}

